# Appium App launch loading all network calls on App home

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, instruments

I have a very peculiar problem with Appium when I am launching my App. My app has some networks calls that need to happen at particular module in the App ( only when user scrolls to the module) , so lets says If I am in user info module network requests for user info need to happen and when user scrolls to user registration module network calls for registration module needs to happen.

When I launch my app manually and watch the network calls in proxy they are loaded one by one when I scroll to user module but when App is launched by Appium and its on the home screen of the App it would just start calling all the network calls in the App for the module which are not even visible in the App ( device is proxied and I am looking a the http get request/response).

Does any one have any idea what would trigger in appium which just somehow will call all network calls on home screen of the App wihtout even scrolling to the module.